# Accessing Slim framework in your own classes

Tags: php, slim

I'm using Slim Framework version 3.

I've followed the [tutorial](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html) on creating an app. Part of this involves setting up a `classes` directory where you can put your own PHP classes.

What I can't understand is how you can access Slim inside those. For example if I have a class `src/classes/Users.php` and wanted to use the Slim Response code e.g.

```
return $response->withStatus(302)->withHeader('Location', 'login');
```

Obviously, `$response`, is not accessible at that point. It only seems to be in `index.php` where each callback recieves it as an argument.

Do I have to pass something to every constructor of my own classes, or `use` or `require` statements in my classes?

Comment: You should pass whatever you need into your classes, read more on dependency injection: http://www.phptherightway.com/#dependency_injection

Comment: @JimL Thanks for the link but I need specific pointers on doing this, not just the theory. Basically all I'm trying to do is use the Response object (or whatever you call it) in my Users.php class. I don't know what to pass to my class, or where.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say when domain layer components need to access application level components - this is a code smell. So, consider doing things otherwise, request object describes **request**. Request contains some data, and that data should be passed to your `User` class, not request object itself.

If you still wish to use `Request` object in `Users` class, simply pass it as argument, like this:

```
// in your routes
$app->post('users', function($request, $response) {
    $user = new User;
    $user->hydrateAndPersist($request); // there you pass it as argument
});

// in your user class
class User
{
    public function hydrateAndPersist(
        \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request,
        \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response // yes, you force yourself into injecting response object
    ) {
        // request is here, let's extract data from it
        $submittedData = $request->getParams();
        // terrible indeed, but this is just an example:
        foreach ($submittedData as $prop => $value) {
            $this->prop = $value;
        }
        $result = $this->save();
        return $response->withJson($result);
    }
}
```

However, in this case your `User` class is coupled heavily with PSR-7 request and response objects. Sometimes coupling is not a problem, but in your case `User` class belongs to domain layer (since it describes User entity), while `$request` and `$response` are components of application layer.

Try to reduce coupling:

```
$app->post('users', function($request, $response) {

    $submittedData = $request->getParams();

    $user = new User;
    $result = $user->hydrateAndPersist($submittedData);
    // response is already declared in this scope, let's "put" result of the operation into it
    $response = $response->withJson($result);
    return $response;
});

class User
{
    public function hydrateAndPersist(array $data) : bool
    {
        $result = false;
        foreach ($submittedData as $prop => $value) {
            $this->prop = $value;
        }
        $result = $this->save();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

See the benefit? `User::hydrateAndPersist` now accepts array as argument, it has no knowledge of `$request` and `$response`. So, it is not tied to HTTP (`PSR-7` describes HTTP messages), it can work with anything. Classes separated, layers separated, ease of maintenance.

To sum up: you can access `$request` object in your `User` class by simply passing `$request` to one of `User` methods. However, this is poor design that will reduce maintainability of your code.